# How do you place redstone dust?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

How do you place redstone dust in Minecraft Pocket Edition. I looked at my redstone book but it doesn't tell you. I've tried just placing it like a block too but it doesn't work.

Comment: Please don't change the tag again.  We use a different tag for the pocket edition because of the significant differences in that version compared to the desktop version.

Answer (score 3):

As of Pocket Edition Alpha 0.13.0 (released on 19<sup>th</sup> of November 2015), redstone dust can be placed on opaque and transparent blocks, upside-down slabs, upside-down stairs and hoppers. To place it, tap on a block while holding on redstone dust.

Source: [Redstone on Minecraft Gamepedia](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Redstone)

Answer (score 1):

Redstone dust cannot be placed in pocket edition, it is a crafting material, nothing more.